# Filter BCS Data by Users AD Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, bcs, external-content-type, profile-sync

I'd like to know if it is possible (and if so, how) to filter the BCS data results by the AD group a user belongs to.

For example. User A belongs to AD group 'group1'. In the external data that SharePoint pulls in, department '500' has a column that has the value 'group1' in it. When User A logs in and views the external data, it sees they belong to 'group 1' and it only shows them department '500' as a result. User A would not be able to see any other department's data other than '500'. OR the user would log into a blank view and have a filter to select only the department ('500') that they have permission to view.

This would prevent having to create preset filters on individual pages with specific permissions. There might be 50 departments for one report. Instead of 50 pages, 1 page would be ideal.

I am using SharePoint online Government/G3 setup with DIRSYNC for AD groups. I am already using AD groups for SharePoint permission and audience purposes.

We are open to code/setup solutions as well as third party add-ons.

Thank you!

Comment: I´m facing exactly the same question. I just found this article that may help in a way. I didn´t try it yet (about to do so in the next few hours). Good luck on that and let me know if it works (also, if you found a different way to solve this :)) http://www.rayterrill.com/securing-sharepoint-external-lists-bcs-by-user-account/

Comment: This one also looks fine :). I´ll try it today. http://www.thesharepointbar.com/?p=340